# Display the first characters of an unsigned char*

Tags: c++, printf, unsigned-char

I have the following code (I stripped down the useless parts):

```
unsigned char* decrypted= (unsigned char *) malloc(500);
bufSize = operations.RSADecrypt(newEncrypted, bufSize, key, decrypted);
printf("Test: %s", decrypted);
```

And I would like to display only the `bufSize` first characters of `decrypted` because actually it displays a lot of nonsense characters!

Comment: just put a zero at the end to terminate the string because printf expects asciz.  decrypted[bufSize]=0; then printf.  ok, now watch a zillion answers show up saying the same thing.

Comment: Hi. Please never tag questions both C and C++ again, unless you ask for a difference.

Comment: @Eregrith the code is probably in C++ (member function), so the cast is necessary.

Comment: Right, sorry. the question was tagged C and C++, as always, so I assumed it was C because of malloc. Should've paid more attention to that `.RSADecrypt` XD...

Comment: If `decrypted` is data, not string, It's better to print it as hex because some of characters may not be printable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `"%.*s"` format specifier:

```
printf("Test: %.*s", bufSize, decrypted);
```

which instructs `printf()` to write the first `bufSize` characters from `decrypted`.

Answer (score 3):

You can limit the length with the format specifier:

```
printf ("Test: %-20.20s", decrypted);
```

For a version using a variable `bufSize`:

```
printf ("Test: %-*.*s", bufSize, bufSize, decrypted);
```

Note that this forces the length to *exactly* that many characters, padded with spaces on the right if need be. If you want a shorter string to be shorter in the output (irrelebant in your case if the string is, as indicated, always longer than what you want output), you can use:

```
printf ("Test: %.*s", bufSize, decrypted);
```

Comment: How would he do that with `bufSize`?

Comment: You only need `printf("Test: %.*s", bufSize, decrypted);`

Answer (score 1):

If you are 'allowed' to modify the `decrypted` string. You can simply add a terminator to it:

```
decrypted[bufSize] = 0;
```

So `printf()` will only print the buffer contents.

If you are not allowed to add a custom char to the `decrypted` buffer you need to copy the contents to a temporary buffer and use that buffer in your `printf()`:

```
unsigned char* tmp = (unsigned char *) malloc(bufSize + 1);
strncpy(tmp, decrypted, bufSize);
tmp[bufSize] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like that you said the pointer contained nonsense. Its not nonsense, its residual memory. There is a good chance you expect and want this area to be set to zero. Try the following, where `calloc` sets the `malloc` bits to zero.

```
unsigned char* decrypted= (unsigned char *) calloc(500,sizeof(char));
bufSize = operations.RSADecrypt(newEncrypted, bufSize, key, decrypted);
printf("Test: %s", decrypted);
```

Comment: `sizeof(*decrypted)` would ensure you didn't miss the `unsigned`